# How to change views in controller when the first view has some quit animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

In my `viewController`, there are two separate "custom views". And the first view has some quit animations, while the second view has some enter animations. The question is how could I change my view in my `viewController` exactly after the first view's quit animation is done? I have tried the `view.hidden` property, but it lost both the quit and the enter animations. I also tried to add some `animateWithDuration` thing and put the `switchView` method in the completion block, which turned out to fail, too.
Here is the code of my `viewController`:

```
@interface PopingViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) HomepageView *homepage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) AboutView *about;
@end

@implementation PopingViewController

- (void)switchView
{
    self.homepage = nil;
    self.about = [[AboutView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    self.about.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.about];
}

- (IBAction)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    // the onTouch method basically does some quit animations which take about 1 sec
    [self.homepage onTouch:[sender locationInView:self.homepage]];
    [self switchView];// it will execute before the animations are finished!
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.homepage = [[HomepageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    self.homepage.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.homepage];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should implement view controller containment.

Answer (score 0):

If they are just plain UIView subclasses then you could implement the UIView transition with class method **transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion** on UIView.

So, for your case, you would do it like this,

```
- (void)switchView
{

    self.about = [[AboutView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view insertSubView:about belowSubView:self.homepage];
    self.about.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     [UIView transitionFromView:self.homepage toView:self.about duration:0.6 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews completion:^(BOOL completed){ [self.homePage removeFromSuperView]; }];
}
```

Otherwise, if you are adding the UIViewController's view to some view then, you would use the UIViewController containment methods. Look at this for further detail http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6

Comment: Thank you for answering but, it still lost the quit animations of the former custom view. FYI, the 'onTouch' method is the quit animation method, which contains two separate 'animateWithDuration' methods to display animations of the subviews. The whole quit animation takes about 1 sec. And I want the latter view(UIView) to come up after the former view's(UIView) 1-sec quit animation is completely finished.